# undefined result during formatting in hexadecimal form

Tags: matlab

I can't understand what is reason of following result

```
>> format hex
>> 10

ans =

   4024000000000000

>> 12

ans =

   4028000000000000
```

as i know this numbers should be written in hexadecimal format,but  why such result?i have tried different variant for example like this

```
>> x=20;
>> format hex
>> x

x =

   4034000000000000
```

if i will try different format

```
>> format long
>> x=10

x =

    10

>> x=10.456

x =

  10.456000000000000
```

it works nice, so what  is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab is behaving absolutely correct, x=12 creates a 64 bit floating point number witch has the presented hexadecimal representation. What you probably want is:

```
    >>uint32(12)

ans =

   0000000c
```

Comment: but what  is reason for  this/

Comment: In Matlab the default data type is double. `x=12` creates a double and `4028000000000000` is what this actually stored in memory.

Comment: so in any case i always need to use uint32 ?

Comment: uint32 is unsined integer 32 bit. You have the choice between signed and unsigned and 8/16/32 bits. Don't know what you want.